# No bootable device insert bootable device

Tags: bios, acer-aspire

Can't turn on laptop Acer aspire V5 561G(purchased at 2014),always gives this msg,also can't enter bios,pressing f2 but no reaction,is there any solution,where can i download bios or recovery tools if official site don't give it for old laptops?

Answer (score 0):

> Common keys to enter the BIOS are F1, F2, F10, DEL, ESC

Source [article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/enter-bios-computer/). You should be able to get to BIOS (or UEFI config UI) with one of those and see if the system recognizes any disks or USB / DVD drives.

Comment: always F2 enters,I tried others.no reaction

Comment: @Grigor: does the BIOS/UEFI UI list any devices then?

Comment: yes,for example i can see  win/ubuntu install but when i choose its return the same error